# Archived versions of Spyder installers for Windows

Tags: python, conda, spyder

I am trying to find an older stand alone version of Spyder for Windows.  I have Spyder 5.2.2 installed and I am trying to use this with a conda environment that has the 2.2.1 kernels.  The Spyder install will not honor a python 3.9.5 in my conda environment.  I am hoping an older version of Spyder will work.

Are older versions of Spyder stand alone installers for Windows archived anywhere? I do not want/can't install Spyder with conda or pip.

Thanks

Comment: When you say `The Spyder install will not honor a python 3.9.5 in my conda environment`, what do you mean? If you set your conda environment in the interpreter preferences and restart or create a new console it should show you that you are using the selected interpreter. Maybe you aren't restarting/creating a new console after changing the intepreter preference?

Answer (score 1):

All the spyder installers are available for the Spyder repository release page here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases

To find a specific version (>=4.2.0 where the installer started to be build). Go to a specific release and check the `Assets` section. There you should find the different installers available.

Also, be sure to uninstall the previous version installed when doing a new install